# Alternativa ao Overlapping de Sprites

Tags: unity3d, spritesheet, monogame

Provavelmente, você já viu/jogou algum jogo aonde era possível mudar equipamento/roupa/aparência do seu personagem.

Estou construindo um pequeno joguinho para Android que disponibiliza essa função, e atualmente consigo isso usando a técnica de Overlapping de sprites, que é basicamente ter o personagem, e ter os equipamentos desenhados em uma camada acima. Porém, isso faz com que eu, toda vez que tenha uma ideia nova de equipamento (equipamentos únicos, com características diferentes), eu tenha que desenhar essa peça de equipamento em todas as posições existentes (caminhando, usando magia, pulando..). Também estou começando a suspeitar que isso consome uma enorme quantidade de RAM (que pode ser um problema real em celulares menos potentes).

Dando uma pesquisada, vi um usuário do Reddit sugerindo fazer os modelos em 3d, renderizar e depois usar como se fosse 2d, mas não tenho ideia por onde começar a fazer isso, e gostaria de ver se existem outras alternativas antes de tentar isso.

Gostaria de saber se poderiam me indicar alguma alternativa ao Overlapping, que também me permita criar uma customização eficiente de personagens.

Lembrando que estou em um ambiente 2D

Comment: Para um modelo 3d, não seria apenas trocar a textura do objeto? Ao invés de usar o Overlapping?

Comment: @Matheus Acho que sim, mas meu jogo corre em um ambiente 2D, vou colocar isso mais claramente na pergunta

Comment: Umas das técnicas que uso pra tentar otimizar o desempenho é criar sprites separados para cada situação. No seu caso seria 1 sprite pra cada armadura e suas sequencias de movimentos. Também existe uma outra forma demostrada nesse tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qE8cuHI93c

Comment: @Matheus sim, eu tenho sprites separadas pra cada peça de armadura/roupa e suas situações. Mas por exemplo, se o jogador equipar  um capacete de um conjunto, um peitoral de outro, uma perneira de outro e uma luva de outro, serão várias sprites em memória :(

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que há duas possibilidades, uma delas semelhante à que disseste.

1. Utilizar um plugin gratuito disponibilizado pela Unity Technologies: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/79840
2. Imitar o que o plugin citado acima faz: criar um modelo 3D de sprites, com as partes do personagem e animar em 3D. Depois colocar as partes de armadura fixada aos respectivos bones(ossos). Podes fazer ossos específicos para movimento de armadura pra ficar mais bonito.

Na Unity só terá que esconder as armaduras conforme a necessidade.

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou dar uma olhada